# Button Fires Twice - 2 records inserted in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, handler

Running in MasterPage with AutoEventWireup = true.  I cannot change this. 
Button inserts new record in database.
When button hits, two records insert.

```
  <asp:Button ID="AddLab" Text="Add Lab" OnClick="AddLab_OnClick" CssClass="btn" runat="server" />
```

PageDirective:

```
    AutoEventWireup="true"  <- I have tried removing this, setting to false.
```

PageLoad/PreRender show to show you nothing being done here with button:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DbDataReader ddrGrp = rdoGroups();
            if (ddrGrp.HasRows)
            {
                rdoGroup.DataSource = ddrGrp;
                rdoGroup.DataBind();
            }
            ddrGrp.Close();
            // preset filter by lab to true
            CheckBox FiltLabs = (CheckBox)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "FiltLabs");
            FiltLabs.Checked = true;
        }

    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        // nothing yet
        rdoLabs.Items.Clear();
        DbDataReader ddrLab = rdoUserLabs();
        if (ddrLab.HasRows)
        {

            rdoLabs.DataSource = ddrLab;
            rdoLabs.DataBind();
            if (CommonUI.strTest((string)Session["rdoLabs"]))
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["rdoLabs"]) > 0)
                {
                    rdoLabs.SelectedValue = (string)Session["rdoLabs"];
                }
            }
        }
        ddrLab.Close();
        // get group-lab mappings
        cboGroupLab.Items.Clear();
        DbDataReader ddrGroupLab = cboGroupLabsMap();
        if (ddrGroupLab != null)
        {
            if (ddrGroupLab.HasRows)
            {

                cboGroupLab.DataSource = ddrGroupLab;
                cboGroupLab.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void AddLab_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabAdmn labAdd = new LabAdmn();
        TextBox txtLab = (TextBox)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "txtLab");
        CheckBox Active = (CheckBox)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "cboLabActive");
        string[] strArr = new string[] { "lab_id" };
        labAdd.LabName = txtLab.Text;
        labAdd.Active = (bool)Active.Checked;
        // AddLab is where record is fired...see below...
        Hashtable ht = labAdd.AddLab(labAdd, strArr);
        ht = labAdd.AddLab(labAdd, strArr);
        if (ht != null)
        {
            HiddenField hLabId = (HiddenField)CommonUI.FindCtrlRecursive(this.Master, "hLabId");
            hLabId.Value = Convert.ToString(GetHTParm(ht, strArr[0]));
        }


    }
    #endregion AddLab_OnClick

    #region AddLab
    public Hashtable AddLab(LabAdmn labAdmn, string[] colOutputNames)
    {
        DAL myDal = new DAL(DBType, DB);
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        DAL.Parameters[] parms = new DAL.Parameters[]
        {
            new DAL.Parameters("driver_id","A",ParameterDirection.Input),
            new DAL.Parameters("lab_id",labAdmn.LabId,ParameterDirection.InputOutput),
            new DAL.Parameters("active",labAdmn.Active,ParameterDirection.Input),
            new DAL.Parameters("lab_name",labAdmn.LabName,ParameterDirection.Input)
        };
        CommandType cmdType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string cmdText = "asp_Labs_Admin";
        ht = myDal.ExecuteQueryOutput(cmdType, cmdText, colOutputNames, parms, true);
        return ht;

    }
    #endregion AddLab
```

I've read that onclick and runat cause double processing.  If I remove runat, the button won't show since it is a server side button.   If remove the OnClick event, the event never fires regardless if AutoEventWireup is true, false, or removed.

Comment: Could you format the rest of your code as well as it is difficult to read it? Also Prerender is not the place where you'd want to do your data binding. Typically you would do any processing with the control before it gets rendered to html.

Comment: This is going to sound weird. But can you check your page for Image tags which don't point to any images or images that don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are calling the "AddLab" method twice:

```
Hashtable ht = labAdd.AddLab(labAdd, strArr);
        ht = labAdd.AddLab(labAdd, strArr);
```

Comment: Yes, I was in a hurry and after about 12 hours I completely missed that.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, sometimes you just need a second set of eyes =)

Answer (score 1):

Please look somewhere in your code, if you are not attaching a handler to the button twice. Maybe in the Designer there is an event handler attached. Maybe somewhere in your init code.

Try remove your code with the button and place it again, without the onclick attribute in the markup. add in your page or control into the "oninit" following

```
AddLab.Click += this.AddLab_OnClick;
```

But first, try to remove the attribute of the markup and try again, if it still fires twice

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename the AddLab_OnClick() method to something else and assign that in OnClick="" handler? I am thinking AutoEventWireup is triggering the first event and the second one is due to OnClick assignment again..

Also, Try what Luke has suggested. That will prove the event assignments..